# concatenacion con php

Tags: php

El problema es el siguiente intento concatenar dentro de un echo el codigo es el siguiente

```
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
 $dir ="assets/img/";
   {
    echo "<article class='124'>";
    echo "<a href="">";
    echo "<img src="$dir.$columna['foto']." alt="">";
    echo "</a> ";                                  
    echo "</article> ";

}
```

Comment: poner la linea de código **$dir ="assets/img/";** entre el while y la llave es un error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes aprender a escapar las comillas e incluir elementos de array u objetos en las cadenas, por ejemplo:

```
// Escapar comillas
echo "<img src=\"nombre_de_imagen\">";

// Agregar elementos de array u objetos entre llaves
echo "<img src=\"{$array['indice']}\">";
```

Entonces, tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
$dir ="assets/img/";
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )) {
    echo "<article class=\"124\">";
    echo "<a href=\"\">";
    echo "<img src=\"$dir{$columna['foto']}\" alt=\"\">";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</article> ";

}
```

Veo más conveniente usar la estructura HEREDOC, donde no es necesario escapar comillas, pero sí encerrar entre llaves elementos de array u objetos:

```
$dir ="assets/img/";
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )) {
    echo <<<EOT  // Tres "menor que" seguidos de un identificador
        <article class="124">
            <a href="">
                <img src="$dir{$columna['foto']}" alt="">
            </a>
        </article>
EOT; // Esta instrucción debe quedar en la primera columna
// Y es el mismo identificador, seguido de un punto y coma
}
```

Elige la forma que mejor te acomode para codificar, pero asegúrate de escapar las comillas cuando sea necesario y encerrar entre llaves cosas como **$row['columna']** o **$db->row('columna')**.

Answer (score 0):

La línea `$dir = ...` debe ir antes de la línea `while(...`.

Te sugiero revisar la [documentación de la función `while`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php); fíjate especialmente en el código del ejemplo 1.

Comment: La línea $dir = ... debe ir antes de la línea while(...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así para que no hagas tantos echos

```
  <?php
    $dir ="assets/img/"; 
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )){ ?>
        <article class='124'><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $dir.$columna['foto']; ?>" alt=""></a></article>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```